# Add page header and footer to pdf using itext xmlworker

Tags: java, pdf, itext, xmlworker

i want to add a page header and page footer to my generated pdf. I use xmlworker for convert my html content to pdf. 
I want to add a page header and page footer in every page of generated pdf, i have problems to do this task. How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement an HeaderFooter class for your document which implements itexts `PdfPageEventHelper` class.
Just take a look at this [example](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=103).
You want to create a header on each page, so you will just need to override the `onEndPage()` method.
Adding a footer can be done with this methode aswell. You can do so by adding content to the directContentByte using coordinates for the pages bottom like this:

```
ColumnText.showTextAligned(writer.getDirectContent(), Element.ALIGN_CENTER, new Phrase("test"), 
                            rect.getRight()-35, rect.getBottom()-25, 0);
```